# sidebar overlaps on the footer - website created in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

edit: Adding a large of amount of white space (just a bunch of new lines) solved this issue, although I feel this is a bit *medieval* and I'm trying to find a more professional solution.

http://juniorgoldreport.com/about-us/ - is the example if you look down to the bottom right (footer/recent posts).

I understand that it is a `position:absolute` issue and that's why but I can not figure out a solution to this. People online have similar issues that I had and I have found and tried out their solution, but to no end even after playing around with them have I been able to solve it. This is the closest solution I could find:

```
#main {
overflow: hidden; /* needed to stretch parent container since children are floated */
}

#primary.content-area {
width: 68%;
float: left;
}

.site-main .sidebar-container {
position: static;
float: right;
width: 30%;
height: auto;
}

.sidebar .entry-header, .sidebar .entry-content, .sidebar .entry-summary, .sidebar .entry-meta {

padding: 0;
}
```

but then my footer just shoots WAYY down to the bottom of the page (a good 500+ pixels of empty space).

Comment: Maybe fix the footer to the bottom with `position:fixed` and use z-index to move it above the sidebar.

Comment: Also, have you checked out how your nav dropdowns react on hover? This isn't your only problem.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I'll take a look at the position:fixed solution. I'm just worried that this will affect all other pages (which are okay) when I just try to fix the problem with the about pages. I see what you mean about the navbar drop down, are you referring to how it overlaps?

Comment: Yes, also the nav items look kind of awkward, as they are different widths. I noticed that on resize (not _mobile_ resize, but a little wider) the sidebar and main content stack and the sidebar doesn't overlap with the footer.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb the only time I noticed the sidebar overlaps the footer is on the about us page, such as the one I linked. 

What would you suggest to make the nav items more, "eye-friendly"?

Comment: Move the dropdown a little down, and set the `a`'s inside the dropdown items with `display:block`

Comment: The reason why the overlap is only on the about page is because the other pages are longer, so the sidebar never reaches the footer. The about page is shorter, so an easy solution would be to just add some more content.

Comment: The entire solution for the about page makes sense. 
I'm not sure how to drop the nav menu down further, I fixed the display:block and width as well when you want to take a look. 

Thanks again for the feedback so far, it's been excellent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a javascript to add padding of body equals with footer height. 
You can check this fiddle to see how it works [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/todorutandrei/pen/regLzG)

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>Here content</h1>
</div>
<div class="footer">
 <h4>FOOTER</h4>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html{
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.content{
  min-height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;

}
```

JS:

```
// getting footer height
var footerHeight = jQuery('.footer').height();

// add padding for body equals with footerHeight
jQuery('html,body').css({'padding-bottom': footerHeight + 'px'})
```

I hope that this helps you !

Comment: I had to step out from my computer, but when I get back I'll give this a look. It looks rather interesting, thank you! I'll post back on how this potential solution worked.

Comment: If the footer has a fixed height and it no depends by how much content is in footer, you can set body padding from css, like this. .body{padding-bottom: footer_height px}